# How to check if the length of a file's line is only 2 characters?

Tags: python

```
with open(myfile, 'r') as textfile:
    encoder = {}
    decoder = {}

    for line in textfile:
        line = line.replace(' ', '')
        if len(line) != 2:
            print("2")
            return

        if len(line) == 2:
            line = line.replace('', ' ')
            (key, value) = line.split()
            encoder[(key)] = value
            decoder[(value)] = key

            if key in encoder.keys():
                print("3")
```

How to check if the length of a file's line is only 2 characters? If it isn't two characters in length, I would like it to print `"2"`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this code? What's the sample input for which it doesn't work?

Comment: Needs little clarification here, so you mean if there is more than two words, program will print only **2**??

Comment: yes, only want to print "2" if the file doesn't have a line with 2 character @Agent_Orange

Comment: I think the line will also contain a newline character (and possibly a linefeed). You should strip these from your string

Comment: Doesn't `if len(line) != 2: print("2")` make that?

Comment: @MrNobody33 no it doesnt

Comment: So, you want to check all lines of the file and if one of them doesn't have len()==2, then print 2, Yes? But you are trying to see if a line has two words or two characters?

Comment: yes, two character @MrNobody33

Comment: @TeresaDavenport It would help if you gave an example of where your existing code is not doing what you wanted, showing: (a) the line of input, (b) the output you want, (c) the output that you are currently getting.

Answer (score 0):

#### Logic: If you wana count how many words there are in a sentence, you have to count how many spaces there are and add **1** to it!!

Based on your problem, I am attaching a sample code to help count you no. of words in line:

Sample:

```
line="this is sample line"
spaces = line.count(" ")
words = spaces+1
```

Now you can easily compare the variable Words and return respective values for your each conditions!

In this case, your refined code will look like:

```
for line in textfile: 
    words = line.count(" ")+1
    if words != 2: 
        print("2") 
        return 
    else:
        #MoreLogics Here
```

Comment: If you did instead something like `len(line.strip().split())`, this would ignore any leading and trailing whitespace, and then also treat multiple spaces as equivalent to a single space. This is more likely to be what is intended when counting words in a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `print(2)` if one line of the lines of the file has `len!=2`, you could use `any` like this:

```
with open(myfile, 'r') as textfile:

    all_lines = textfile.read().splitlines()
    all_lines=[s.replace('\t', '') for s in all_lines]  #If you want to count '\t', you can erase this line
    if any(map(lambda x: len(x)!=2 , all_lines)):
        print('2')

    encoder = {}

    decoder = {}

    #....
    #Continue the rest of your script...
```

In the case you want to take into account the characters `'\n'` and `'\t'`m, you can define :   `all_lines = textfile.readlines()`.